# Find files in OS X by creation time, date is irrelevant to the search

Tags: macos, bash, csv

I have an hourly cron that has been dumping CSV files into one folder for a year. I now have a need to grab all the files created sometime in the 8:00PM hour that are all located in this folder so that I can import just them into a database. How can I find and copy just these files out to another folder? The filename is structured like this: `2014_9_1_20_10_55.csv` or said another way, `yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss.csv`

Comment: This worked:     cp directory/foo_bar_*_*_*_20_*_*.csv new_directory/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a wildcard:

```
cp *_*_*_20_*_*.csv other_folder
```

Comment: That was close, but it also grabbed 2013_12_20_15_3_3.csv and others with a 20 for the day of the month.

Comment: I've updated the wildcard to make use of a bash extension that should prevent that.

Comment: I put back my original answer. I just tried it, and it didn't match that filename. My wildcard requires there to be at least 3 underscores before `20`, and at least 2 underscores after it. There's no way it can match that filename.

Comment: Is it possible you have names like `foo_2013_12_20_15_3_3.csv` with an extra field before the year? That would cause my wildcard to match too much.

Comment: You are totally right... there were some with foo_ going on.